# ionic 1.0.0 model ion-modal-view does not work with Android back button

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, modal-view

After I upgraded to 1.0.0, the modal view does not hide after pressing Android back button, instead the view which shows modal view goes back, this bug sucks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `modal.hide()` on the same back button of your modal.

Example:

```
<button ng-click="modal.hide()"></button>
```